# Flask wtforms check if username already exists / flashing errors

Tags: flask, flask-sqlalchemy, wtforms

I have a basic registration/login built that works as intended. The issue I am having is that I can not figure out how to check if a username is already in use and then flash a message that says so.

**My route**

```
@app.route("/signup", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def signup():
    form = RegisterForm()

    if form.validate_on_submit():
        hashed_password = generate_password_hash(form.password.data, method='sha256')
        new_user = User(username=form.userName.data, email=form.email.data, password=hashed_password)
        db.session.add(new_user)
        db.session.commit()

        flash("Registration successful...please log in!")
        return redirect(url_for('login'))

    return render_template("signup.html", form=form)
```

**My User Model**

```
class User(UserMixin, db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(20), unique=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(50), unique=True)
    password = db.Column(db.String(80))
```

**my HTML (errors div)**

```
{% for field, errors in form.errors.items() %}
    <div class="alert alert-error">
        {{ form[field].label }}: {{ ', '.join(errors) }}
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possibility is to write a [custom validator](https://wtforms.readthedocs.io/en/2.3.x/validators/#custom-validators) which queries the database for an already existing user with the name and throws an error if the query is successful.

```
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms.validators import DataRequired
from wtforms.validators import ValidationError

class RegisterForm(FlaskForm):
    
    # ...
    
    username = StringField(
        'Username',
        validators=[
            DataRequired(),
            # ...
        ])

    # ...
    
    def validate_username(self, field):
        if User.query.filter_by(username=field.data).first():
            raise ValidationError('Username already in use.')
```